# Standing during a wedding

Tags: halacha, wedding, standing-sitting

During the bracha that weds that chassan and kallah are we required in the audience to stand? is it a minhag? Can we sit? What's your source?

Comment: Very closely related (and at least a near duplicate of #1): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17243

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Standing up at the Chuppa when the Kallah passes by](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17243/standing-up-at-the-chuppa-when-the-kallah-passes-by)

Comment: https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/11/2016/whats-truth-standing-chatan-kallah/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that we do at a wedding is paralleling the process of receiving the Torah at Mount Sinai.

This relationship is based upon Shir HaShirim which compares the relationship between G-d and the Jewish people to that of a husband and wife. This same idea is repeated in the book of Hoshea. It is also expressed in the custom to recite the Tikun Leil Shavuot on Shavuot.

> השם תיקון ליל שבועות הגיע מספר הזוהר, שם מופיעה המילה הארמית "תיקון", שפירושה בעברית- "קישוט". הכוונה היא שהאנשים שאומרים את ה"תיקון" הם השושבינים המקשטים את הכלה- התורה, במהלך הלילה, לקראת כניסתה לחופה למחרת בבוקר, בעת קריאת עשרת הדיברות.

[https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/תיקון_ליל_שבועות](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA)

And also the Sephardic custom the the recital of 'the Ketubah', the 'Wedding Contract' composed by Israel ben Moses Najara.

https://www.ou.org/holidays/shavuot/akdamut_and_ketuvah/
.

The practice of standing during the walk to the chuppah is based upon Shemot 19:17 which says,"Moshe brought the people out from the camp to greet G-d's presence and ***they stood*** under the mountain.

> וַיּוֹצֵא משֶׁה אֶת הָעָם לִקְרַאת הָאֱלֹהִים מִן הַמַּחֲנֶה וַיִּתְיַצְּבוּ בְּתַחְתִּית הָהָר:

The act of standing during the bracha is based upon, Shemot 20:15 which says, "And all the people saws the thunder and the lightening and the sound of the shofar and the mountain smoking, and the people were afraid and moved away and ***stood*** from a distance.

> כָל הָעָם רֹאִים אֶת הַקּוֹלֹת וְאֶת הַלַּפִּידִם וְאֵת קוֹל הַשֹּׁפָר וְאֶת הָהָר עָשֵׁן וַיַּרְא הָעָם וַיָּנֻעוּ וַיַּעַמְדוּ מֵרָחֹק:

Comment: I love the first sentence. +1. Is there a source for this? (haven't re-read Aryeh Kaplan's Made in Heaven since I got married 17 years ago...)

Comment: @YaacovDeane So should people stand during all the brachas that are said under the chuppah?

Comment: @SAH With tongue in cheek, only if you experience a reversal of perception, like they did at Har Sinai. They saw the thunder and heard the lightning! Otherwise, follow the custom of the place.

Comment: @YaacovDeane OK!

Answer (score 1):

The HaElef Lecha Shlomo 3:115  brings from the Tikkunei Zohar Tikun 10 that everyone in attendance needs to stand with the chassan and Kallah when the sheva brachos is recited under the chuppah,and it would be prohibited to sit during the brachos. Certainly it is appropriate to be concerned for the Tikkunei Zohar(Rav Kluger writes this).